# how to use be and is/are hereby?

Tags: meaning, grammar, be

Please help me to explain the grammar of this sentence belows:

any Director or any person (s) authorized by the Directors be and is/are hereby authorized, either solely or jointly, to sign and execute the Document.

I don't undersand how to use "be" after directors " *authorized by the Directors be and is/are hereby authorized"*. Please help me

thanks

Comment: It's a strange one, but it's a legal document. The 'be' seems redundant to me, but might have a specific meaning in this context.

Comment: Did you leave out the start of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

We really need more context. I suspect the cited text isn't really an "independent **sentence**". For example, perhaps it's one of several "bullet points" listed under some context-setting initial text, such as ***The Board of Trustees are agreed that...***

...in which context subjunctive *...that the Directors **be** authorized [to blah blah]* is perfectly okay, as is *...that the Directors **are** authorized [to blah blah]*.

Both verb forms represent "performative utterances", in that *making the statement is equivalent to providing the authorization* - same as, for example, *I [hereby] **promise** to tell the truth*.

Answer (score 0):

If you Google "be and is/are", there are a number of similar usages, which seem mostly to be legal documents from Hong Kong and Singapore.

For example,

> It was resolved that ... the person(s) named in Appendix 2 herein (each, an “Applicant Authorized Signatory, be and is/are hereby authorized to act singly for and on behalf of the Applicant to:

In this example (which isn't true for all examples), either *be* or *is/are* would be grammatical, but including both is redundant. I expect somebody made a grammatical mistake at some point, and it was used as a template and copied. Note that this document is missing an end quote and parenthesis  after "Signatory", so presumably it wasn't read very carefully.

At a wild guess, I'd say it might have originated when somebody didn't understand the meaning of the subjunctive *be* and added *is/are* to make the meaning clearer.

Comment: My guess: it's a compression of an older formula that does two things: first reminds the reader of the speaker's authority to command that something *be* done, and then declares that it hereby *is* done.